# SignalR posting from server not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

This is my first try with signalR and I don't know if my code is correct, this code is just for test, signalR should post to all clients when called from Controller Action:
Here is what I did:

1.Installed SignalR using NuGet(I had a slight problem with bundling/minification) so I am importing signalR js separatly

2.Created Hub in new folder SingalR:

```
    [HubName("messageHub")]
    public class MessagesHub : Hub
    {
        public void AddMessage(string htmlstring)
        {
            Clients.addMessage(htmlstring);
        }
    }
```

3.Created client side script, I only needed Server -> Client and not both ways:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/SignalR/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="content-wrapper">
        <h1 id="lq" class="subtitle">Public Messages</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () 
    {
        var message = $.connection.messageHub;

        message.addMessage= function (htmlstring) 
        {
            $(htmlstring).insertAfter('#lq');
        };

        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

4.Here is Action wich should post message to all clients when someone visits it.

```
   public ActionResult Index(int id, string title)
   {
     MessagesModel model = new MessagesModel(id);
     var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalR.MessagesHub>();
     hubContext.Clients.addMessage("Sample Message");
     return View(model);
   }
```

So I open Firefox and I can see negotiate sucess in firebug, the I open chrome and go to this page Index just to see "Sample Message" inserted into page in Firefox but nothing happens, what am I missing?

**Update:** 
I get "/signalr/hubs" not found when navigating away from page in Firebug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may sound silly but the problem was the client and server methods where named the same althought the casing was different, so I just changed:

```
[HubName("messageHub")]
    public class MessagesHub : Hub
    {
        public void AddMessage(string htmlstring)
        {
            Clients.addMessage(htmlstring);
        }
    }
```

to:

```
  [HubName("messageHub")]
        public class MessagesHub : Hub
        {
            public void SendMessage(string htmlstring)
            {
                Clients.addMessage(htmlstring);
            }
        }
```